# short or simple solution for putting values from label to column in excel

Tags: c#, excel, winforms, excel-interop

Good day, anyone can help me with this problem, I have a code here that counts number of fruits from Column B to Column AF (31 days)
I used switch that would be case 1 to case 31. I want my code to be simple or in a loop. 31 case is just too long. By the way my code work, I just want it be short.

Here's my code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application OfficeExcel;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook OfficeWorkBook;
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet OfficeSheet;

        var dtpMonth = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("MMMM");
        var dtpYear = dateTimePicker1.Value.Year;
        var MonthYear = dtpMonth + " - " + dtpYear;
        var dtpDay = dateTimePicker1.Value.Day;
        try
        {
            OfficeExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            OfficeExcel.Visible = true;

            int appletotal = Convert.ToInt32(lblappletotal.Text);
            int bananatotal = Convert.ToInt32(lblbananatotal.Text);
            int orangetotal = Convert.ToInt32(lblorangetotal.Text);
            int grapestotal = Convert.ToInt32(lblgrapestotal.Text);

            switch (dateTimePicker1.Value.Day.ToString())
            { 
                case "1":
                     OfficeWorkBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(OfficeExcel.Workbooks.Add(""));
                     OfficeSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)OfficeWorkBook.ActiveSheet;

                    OfficeSheet.Cells[3,1] = "apple";
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[4,1] = "banana";
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[5,1] = "orange";
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[6,1] = "grapes";

                    OfficeSheet.Cells[2, 2] = dtpDay + dtpMonth ;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[3, 2] = appletotal; // variable
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[4, 2] = bananatotal;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[5, 2] = orangetotal;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[6, 2] = grapestotal;

                    OfficeExcel.Visible = true;



                    OfficeWorkBook.SaveAs("D:\\fruits\\" + MonthYear + ".xls", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlExcel7, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                                    false, false, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange,
                                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);


                     break;


                case "2":
                    OfficeWorkBook = OfficeExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\\fruits\\" + MonthYear + ".xls");
                    OfficeSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)OfficeWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

                    OfficeSheet.Cells[2, 3] = dtpDay + dtpMonth;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[3, 3] = appletotal;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[4, 3] = bananatotal;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[5, 3] = orangetotal;
                    OfficeSheet.Cells[6, 3] = grapestotal;

                    OfficeExcel.Visible = true;
                    OfficeWorkBook.Save();

                    break;
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    so On.....
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
int DayCell = dateTimePicker1.Value.Day+1;
OfficeSheet.Cells[2, Daycell] = dtpDay + dtpMonth ;
```

Put the day value to a variable and use it as an indexer.

Comment: I think you use switch again right? if i'm wrong can you show me how to do it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You do not need switch anymore.